# Separate png vs transition:opacity for :hover state - which is better (efficiency)?

Tags: css, hover, png, css-transitions, opacity

I'm having several buttons that I want to get darker when user hovers over. Which method is better (faster, more efficient, more safe in terms of browser compatibility):

1. Create 2 separate .png images, one normal one _hover
2. Use `transition:opacity` css property.

Images are small, each approx. 600 bytes big (20x20 pxl), but having approximately 30 of them makes me wonder which method is better in terms of speed efficiency and older browsers support (but not to the point trying to please IE6 either)

Answer (score 0):

if opacity is doing your job of darkening the image-

#### Use it.

You said darkening image? so i assume u start with lower opacity value and chage to something higher.opacity is more like transparency of the pic-dosent darken it.

If opacity is not giving the desired results you can use hover change of image-use image sprites this way you dont have to request for 60 svg's(30 svgs considering you use a combination of 2 pics instead of one)
[LINK for sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).

I suggest using SVG filter gives you better image effects-[Browser support](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)